# Store random string in Session, which gets overwritten, when I call it through another PHP-File

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, oop, session

I created a form, which includes an hidden input and its value is set by an function.

```
<?php
    class Token {
        public static function generate(){
            return $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        }
    }
?>
```

This is called like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
```

I sent it via JavaScript/AJAX to another file (e.g. "form.php"), which contains something like:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   @require_once 'Token.class.php';

   echo $_POST['token'] . " => " . $_SESSION['token']; // different tokens, why?
   // $_POST['token'] is the one, that I want
   // and so on...
?>
```

Why do the values change, when I type in: `<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>` ?

This is my project [stored on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/idj1njhl8p2pf4u/project.rar)

Comment: Maybe your second file calls generate method as well as first one?

Comment: Nope, if it was so easy :/

Comment: Try checking if it exists, multiple requests may be happening.

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside all files? @JonLamer

Comment: Yes, it is in all files.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are generating new one every time you are entering a site?

```
<?php
    class Token {
        public static function generate(){
            if(isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token']) return $_SESSION['token'];
            else return $_SESSION['token'] = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        }
    }
?>
```

PS. You may want to use `md5(uniqid())` instead.

Comment: Yes, I actually do this, when refresh my "index.php", but not in my "form.php", this should be the same, I think

Comment: And where are you posting to? Not to same page?

Comment: It is posted to "form.php", where is should be validated, but is this a behavior of AJAX?

Comment: You need to show whole code, as probably it is being regenerated in form.php before you echo it.

Comment: Is it a problem, when I post a dropbox link? I added it to my post.